# beta coefficients and p-value with l Logistic Regression in Python

Tags: python, regression, logistic-regression

I would like to perform a simple logistic regression (1 dependent, 1 independent variable) in python. All of the documentation I see about logistic regressions in python is for using it to develop a predictive model. I would like to use it more from the statistics side. How do I find the `Odds ratio`, `p-value`, and `confidence interval` of a simple logistic regression on python?

```
X = df[predictor]
y = df[binary_outcome]

model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X,y)

print(#model_stats)
```

with an ideal output of `Odds ratio`, `p-value`, and `confidence interval`

Comment: What is your question? Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using `LogisticRegression()` from `sklearn`. You don't get to estimate p-value confidence interval from that. You can use statsmodels, also note that statsmodels without formulas is a bit different from sklearn (see comments by @Josef), so you need to add a intercept using `sm.add_constant()` :

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

y = np.random.choice([0,1],50)
x = np.random.normal(0,1,50)

model = sm.GLM(y, sm.add_constant(x), family=sm.families.Binomial())
results = model.fit()
results.summary()

Generalized Linear Model Regression Results
Dep. Variable:  y   No. Observations:   50
Model:  GLM Df Residuals:   48
Model Family:   Binomial    Df Model:   1
Link Function:  logit   Scale:  1.0000
Method: IRLS    Log-Likelihood: -33.125
Date:   Sat, 09 Jan 2021    Deviance:   66.250
Time:   16:21:51    Pearson chi2:   50.1
No. Iterations: 4       
Covariance Type:    nonrobust       
coef    std err z   P>|z|   [0.025  0.975]
const   -0.0908 0.309   -0.294  0.769   -0.696  0.514
x1  0.5975  0.361   1.653   0.098   -0.111  1.306
```

The coefficient is in log odds, you can simply convert that to odds ratio. The [0.025 0.975] columns are the 95% confidence interval for the log odds. Check out [help page for more info](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/glm.html)

Comment: Note, statsmodels does not add constant automatically when not using formulas.

Comment: yes i missed that. thanks for pointing that out